# What is the power set of the cross product of A= {a} and B = {1,2}?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let A = {a} and B = {1, 2}. Find each of the following:

a) A x B

b) P (A x B)

c) P(A) and P(B)

d) P(A) x P(B)

I know a) is A x B = { (a,1) , (a, 2) }. I am unsure about b).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. The power set has all possible subsets.  The power set of a set with $n$ elements has $2^n$ elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ P(A\times B) =\{\emptyset , \{(a,1)\}, \{(a,2)\}, \{(a,1), (a,2)\}\}$$

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Just do it.

If $K$ is a set then $P(K)$ is the set of all subsets and to "make" a subset you take every element and either.... include it or not.

$K = A\times B = \{(a,1), (a,2)\}$ it has two elements:  $(a,1)$ and $(a,2)$.

So you can have the following subsets:

1) a subset that does not contain $(a,1)$ and does not contain $(a,2)$:  That is $\emptyset$.

2) a subset that contains $(a,1)$ but does not contain $(a,2)$:  That is $\{(a,1)\}$.

3) a subset that does not contain $(a,1)$ but does contains $(a,2)$: That is $\{(a,2)\}$.

4) a subset that contains $(a,1)$ and contains $(a,2)$: That is $\{(a,1),(a,2)\}$ (which is $A\times B$ btw.)

So those are the four possible subsets.

So $P(A\times B) = \{\emptyset, \{(a,1)\}, \{(a,2)\}, \{(a,1), (a,2)\}\}$.